# Sim Dongle device for sending sms using asp.net MVC web application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sms, gsm, dongle

Is is possible to use dongle device for sending sms in a web application using asp.net mvc 5.
If so can any one give me some idea how is it possible or suggest me any good tutorials for this?

Comment: Do you have access to MBN API (mbnapi.dll) from asp.net?  This is the Windows .NET API for sending SMS.

Comment: Not yet, I have no idea, actually  next month I have to start working on a project, so I am preparing for it.

Comment: Find out if you can access MBN API from asp.net.  If yes, then that's how to do it.